# iOS get request to Rails API with Parameters

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api, parameters, afnetworking

In my rails app

Locations have_many Beers

Beers belong_to location

When the iOS app calls `locations/%@/beers.json` I want the Beers Controller to respond with beers that belong only to the location_id that is being called from my iOS app.

Here is the request sent from the client when a user taps on location 1.

```
Started GET "/locations/1/beers.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-09 11:26:16 -0700
Processing by BeersController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"location_id"=>"1"}
  Beer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "beers".* FROM "beers" 
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Here is my Beer Controller code

```
class BeersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @beers = Beer.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @beers }
    end
  end
```

Right now, this returns a list of all beers to the client regardless of their location_id.

So far I've tried

```
class BeersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @beers = Beer.find(params[:location_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @beers }
    end
  end
```

But that crashes the iOS app even though I get a status 200

```
 Started GET "/locations/1/beers.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-09 11:19:35 -0700
    Processing by BeersController#index as JSON
      Parameters: {"location_id"=>"1"}
      Beer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "beers".* FROM "beers" WHERE "beers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
    Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

In the above request shouldn't it be

`Beer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "beers".* FROM "beers" WHERE "beers"."location_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["location_id", "1"]`]

How can I change my controller so that it responds with beers that belong only to the location_id that is being sent by the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the action you're looking for is `show`, not `index` if you're looking for a RESTful service.

To fix the error you mention you need to change your query to:

```
@beers = Beer.where(:location_id => params[:location_id])
```

Assuming `location_id` is the field you're looking for.

I would look hard at your routes, which define your urls.  They don't follow normal conventions.

`/locations/...` would belong to a `Location` resource.

`/beers/...` would belong to a `Beer` resource.

You're messing with convention (which works against you) with your current routes.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Brown, that did fix my error on the client so I marked this as the answer. I do think I need to look closely at my routes so I'll ask another question to address that. Thanks.